# Issue regarding closing Facebook Feed dialog

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

We are developing an web application where we want to share content using Facebook feed. Following the tutorial we are able to integrate and able to share with feed. However ,in chrome(version 43+)the pop-up that opens is not getting closed on its own. User needs to explicitly close the pop-up. The popup however is getting closed on its own in Firefox.

In Chrome, after submitting the feed, the popup becomes empty with just the Facebook url www.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/feed in the address bar.

We searched similar issues. They were quite old [posted before 2012]. We tried solution in those posts but could not solve our issue. There is similar issue posted in May-2015 but no solution is mentioned there. And the question is down voted.

We are using Facebook javascript sdk's UI method.

```js
     
  FB.ui({
          display: 'popup',
          method: 'feed',
          link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',//sample link
          picture: imageURL,//sample picture link
          name: 'Facebook Feed',
          caption: 'Reference Caption',
          description: 'Using Feeds to share content with users.'
      }, function(response) {
              console.log(response);                    
    });-
```

Any help or pointers to solve this issue will be of great help.

thanks
Soumen

Comment: Facebook’s JS SDK should handle this by itself; since it doesn’t, you should file a bug report. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: This works fine on chrome. i tested the feed dialog with the fbrell sample that FB has setup. can you confirm the browser version and java version you are using?

Comment: Yes I have got the solution. the solution is You have to call the FB.ui() method inside the response of FB.getLoginStatus()  eg. 

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if("connected" === response.status){
                 FB.ui({

                 })
            }
}

Comment: @SoumenNaskar Did this solution is a patch or you have answer from some facebook official?
Did you test it on explorer/edge?

Comment: Sorry @AlexanderGorelik I can't refer you the exact source because I lost it. But I can tell you that It is not from Facebook Official. I found it in a bolg.